# Searching data inside multiple Apache-Kafka log files using DumpLogSegments

Tags: bash, apache-kafka

**Background**

Need to search data for validation in kafka log files. Not trying to use command line consumer.

**Tool**

Using [Dump Log Segment Tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-DumpLogSegment)

**Problem**

The `--files` parameter requires file to be `,` separated

```
--files <file1, file2, ...>             REQUIRED: The comma separated list of  
                                        data and index log files to be dumped
```

Is there any way to look at all the files under a directory ? Tried `*log` but it looks only at first file in the directory.

Or

Scripting a small program is the only option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked up some random script which worked for my purpose.

**Checking data per file**

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname="$1"
tosearch="$2"
files=""

if [[ -s $dirname ]] ; then
    for filename in $(ls -d $dirname/*log); do
            count=$(bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files "$filename" --print-data-log | grep "$tosearch" | wc -l)
            echo "$filename : $count"
    done
fi
```

**Checking data in all files collectively**

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname="$1"
tosearch="$2"
files=""

if [[ -s $dirname ]] ; then
    for filename in $(ls -d $dirname/*log); do
            files+="$filename,"
    done
    newfiles=$(echo "$files" | sed 's/,$//')
    count=$(bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files "$files" --print-data-log | grep "$tosearch" | wc -l)
    echo "$count"
fi
```